# How to add /api before swagger-ui.html

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, request-mapping

How to add default parameter before swagger-ui.html

Like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/swagger-ui.html
```

What I have integrated so far:

Pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

SwaggerConfig.java:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {                                    
    @Bean
    public Docket api() { 
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)  
          .select()                                  
          .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())              
          .paths(PathSelectors.any())                          
          .build();                                           
    }
}

Do I have to map "swagger-ui.html" to something with @RequestMapping?
```

Comment: consider taking a look at this documentation https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
    .host("www.mydomain.com")
    .pathProvider(new RelativePathProvider(servletContext) {
        @Override
        public String getApplicationBasePath() {
            return "/myapi";
        }
    });
```

in case you run into any issues: https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1443

Comment: could I directly add server.servlet = /api in application.yml instead?

Answer (score 0):

Include the following annotations at class level in SwaggerConfig.java:

@PropertySource("classpath:swagger.properties") and
@ComponentScan

Then create the swagger.properties file in the resources directory (same location as your application.properties file)